# VBA: Updating a Record Set Based on current data

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I'm kind of new to vba access and just ran into a HUGE issue with the code. Let me explain, I have a form that loads the data from a current record and allows the user to edit it. Currently i'm creating the save button so the data that has been changed is properly updated in the database. what I have is a check to make sure the data in the textbox is equal to the data in the record set. The problem is if the data is null in the database it will run as if it is equal to the data in the textbox even though the textbox has like "Updated Group" in it. To me this is a bit of an oversight and kinda of disappointing. My question is does anyone know a workaround to this issue?

Thanks in advance for any info.

**HERE'S THE ANSWER:** If RstRecSet("GroupName").Value **& ""** <> txtGroupNameEdit.Value **& ""** -Wayne

Here's my code:

```
    Dim searchGroup As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim RstRecSet As DAO.Recordset
Dim Rst As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
searchGroup = txtGroupNrEdit
Set RstRecSet = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblGroupHeader Where groupNum like '*" & searchGroup & "*';", dbOpenDynaset)
Set Rst = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblAuditTable;", dbOpenDynaset)

If RstRecSet("GroupName").Value <> txtGroupNameEdit.Value Or RstRecSet("PlanStartDate").Value <> txtStartDateEdit.Value _
Or RstRecSet("CanDate").Value <> txtCanDateEdit.Value Or RstRecSet("ClerkID").Value <> txtClerkIDEdit.Value _
Or RstRecSet("PopulationType").Value <> txtGroupTypeEdit.Value Or RstRecSet("COC").Value <> chkCOCEdit.Value _
Or RstRecSet("CDHFinancialPartner").Value <> cmbCDHEdit.Value Or RstRecSet("CDHProdOptions").Value <> chkCDHEdit.Value _
Or RstRecSet("MemberLevelBenefits").Value <> chkMembBeneEdit.Value Or RstRecSet("Comments").Value <> txtCommentsEdit.Value _
Or RstRecSet("AlsoKnownAs").Value <> txtKnownEdit.Value Or RstRecSet("BCBS").Value <> chkBCBSEdit.Value _
Or RstRecSet("Other").Value <> chkOtherEdit.Value Then
    RstRecSet.Edit
    Rst.AddNew
        If RstRecSet("AlsoKnownAs").Value <> txtKnownEdit.Value Then
        Rst("GroupName").Value = txtGroupNameEdit.Value
        Rst("GroupNum").Value = txtGroupNrEdit.Value
        RstRecSet("AlsoKnownAs").Value = txtKnownEdit.Value
        Rst("AlsoKnownAs").Value = RstRecSet("AlsoKnownAs")
        Rst("DateChanged").Value = Date
        End If
        If RstRecSet("PlanStartDate").Value <> txtStartDateEdit.Value Then
        Rst("GroupName").Value = txtGroupNameEdit.Value
        Rst("GroupNum").Value = txtGroupNrEdit.Value
        RstRecSet("PlanStartDate").Value = txtStartDateEdit.Value
        Rst("PlanStartDate").Value = RstRecSet("PlanStartDate")
        Rst("DateChanged").Value = Date
        End If
        If RstRecSet("CanDate").Value <> txtCanDateEdit.Value Then
        Rst("GroupName").Value = txtGroupNameEdit.Value
        Rst("GroupNum").Value = txtGroupNrEdit.Value
        RstRecSet("CanDate").Value = txtCanDateEdit.Value
        Rst("CanDate").Value = RstRecSet("CanDate")
        Rst("DateChanged").Value = Date
        End If
        If RstRecSet("PopulationType").Value <> txtGroupTypeEdit.Value Then
        Rst("GroupName").Value = txtGroupNameEdit.Value
        Rst("GroupNum").Value = txtGroupNrEdit.Value
        RstRecSet("PopulationType").Value = txtGroupTypeEdit.Value
        Rst("PopulationType").Value = RstRecSet("PopulationType")
        Rst("DateChanged").Value = Date
        End If
        If RstRecSet("CDHFinancialPartner").Value <> cmbCDHEdit.Value Then
        Rst("GroupName").Value = txtGroupNameEdit.Value
        Rst("GroupNum").Value = txtGroupNrEdit.Value
        RstRecSet("CDHFinancialPartner").Value = cmbCDHEdit.Value
        Rst("CDHFinancialPartner").Value = RstRecSet("CDHFinancialPartner")
        Rst("DateChanged").Value = Date
        End If
        If RstRecSet("MemberLevelBenefits").Value <> chkMembBeneEdit.Value Then
        Rst("GroupName").Value = txtGroupNameEdit.Value
        Rst("GroupNum").Value = txtGroupNrEdit.Value
        RstRecSet("MemberLevelBenefits").Value = chkMembBeneEdit.Value
        Rst("MemberLevelBenefits").Value = RstRecSet("MemberLevelBenefits")
        Rst("DateChanged").Value = Date
        End If
        If RstRecSet("Other").Value <> chkOtherEdit.Value Then
        Rst("GroupName").Value = txtGroupNameEdit.Value
        Rst("GroupNum").Value = txtGroupNrEdit.Value
        RstRecSet("Other").Value = chkOtherEdit.Value
        Rst("Other").Value = RstRecSet("Other")
        Rst("DateChanged").Value = Date
        End If
        If RstRecSet("ClerkID").Value <> txtClerkIDEdit.Value Then
        Rst("GroupName").Value = txtGroupNameEdit.Value
        Rst("GroupNum").Value = txtGroupNrEdit.Value
        RstRecSet("ClerkID").Value = txtClerkIDEdit.Value
        Rst("ClerkID").Value = RstRecSet("ClerkID")
        Rst("DateChanged").Value = Date
        End If
        If RstRecSet("COC").Value <> chkCOCEdit.Value Then
        Rst("GroupName").Value = txtGroupNameEdit.Value
        Rst("GroupNum").Value = txtGroupNrEdit.Value
        RstRecSet("COC").Value = chkCOCEdit.Value
        Rst("COC").Value = RstRecSet("COC")
        Rst("DateChanged").Value = Date
        End If
        If RstRecSet("CDHProdOptions").Value <> chkCDHEdit.Value Then
        Rst("GroupName").Value = txtGroupNameEdit.Value
        Rst("GroupNum").Value = txtGroupNrEdit.Value
        RstRecSet("CDHProdOptions").Value = chkCDHEdit.Value
        Rst("CDHProdOptions").Value = RstRecSet("CDHProdOptions")
        Rst("DateChanged").Value = Date
        End If
        If RstRecSet("Comments").Value <> txtCommentsEdit.Value Then
        Rst("GroupName").Value = txtGroupNameEdit.Value
        Rst("GroupNum").Value = txtGroupNrEdit.Value
        RstRecSet("Comments").Value = txtCommentsEdit.Value
        Rst("SpecialConsideration").Value = RstRecSet("Comments")
        Rst("DateChanged").Value = Date
        End If
        If RstRecSet("BCBS").Value <> chkBCBSEdit.Value Then
        Rst("GroupName").Value = txtGroupNameEdit.Value
        Rst("GroupNum").Value = txtGroupNrEdit.Value
        RstRecSet("BCBS").Value = chkBCBSEdit.Value
        Rst("BCBS").Value = RstRecSet("BCBS")
        Rst("DateChanged").Value = Date
        End If
        If RstRecSet("GroupName").Value <> txtGroupNameEdit.Value Then
        Rst("GroupName").Value = txtGroupNameEdit.Value
        Rst("GroupNum").Value = txtGroupNrEdit.Value
        RstRecSet("GroupName").Value = txtGroupNameEdit.Value
        Rst("GroupName").Value = RstRecSet("GroupName")
        Rst("DateChanged").Value = Date
        End If
    Rst.Update
    RstRecSet.Update
End If
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match what you describe it does. It looks like you check, "is anything different?" and if so you actually add a new record in addition to editing a record. I'm not sure what you are actually asking.

Comment: Dont pat attention to the add record that's only for the audit table. The works like you ecplained it; "is anything different? change what is different then". The issue is when lets say "KnownAs" has nothing in the record it wont trigger that "is anything different?" statement(I think because it's null), it just assumes it's the same..

Comment: Null values can cause weird results during comparisons, therefore you need to determine if the recordset field is Null. i.e. 'If RstRecSet("GroupName").Value & "" <> txtGroupNameEdit.Value & "" ....

Comment: Wayne, You're the man. Worked perfectly! If you want to answer the question i'll make it answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null values can cause weird results during comparisons. Try something like the following:

```
If RstRecSet("GroupName").Value & "" <> txtGroupNameEdit.Value & "" Or ...
```

Answer (score 0):

But your save button only needs this one line of code:

If me.dirty then me.dirty = false

Why do you need all this other code and checks? When you edit data in an access form the data is NOT changed or committed to the table UNTIL you allow the saving of data. And MORE important if a control is not changed, then the event code for that control does not run. Therefore it is a HUGE WASTE of time to write tons of code when in fact you don’t need to.

And you can of course (and should) place additional code that checks values and date in the forms before update event. This event occurs before the data from the form is written to the table, and you can thus add code to test for empty text boxes, or have VERY complex code and rules to test the data BEFORE the write of data BACK to the table occurs.

You re-inventing the wheel for nothing here and wasting valuable developer time. You save button only needs the above one line of code to save data.

For preventing the save to occur you can simply place testing and verification code in the forms before update event, and that event will NOT fire if the user does not edit any data. Perhaps you explain what the verification of data problem is. The save button is not required, and keep in mind that ctrl-s, ctrl-f4 and good number of other keys will case a data save, but in ALL cases your testing code in before update event will run and fire.

Comment: Hello Albert, I need the code checks to see if the user has changed data in the form. Let me explain. When the form loads, it loads with the data from recordset, lets say A. The user then has the option to edit the data after which they can click "save". The checks before the record updates are only to make sure the the user has in fact changed a value in a textbox.

This does unfortunately involve me adding in a lot of code. Thanks for your time and letting me know about the dirty property, I honestly had no idea it existed. 

Thanks,